# How to include historical data when disaggregating using td() from tempdisagg?

Tags: r

I have annual CPI data with forecast values extending from 2000 to 2025. I also have historical quarterly data from 2000 Q1 to 2022 Q2. I want to disaggregate the annual CPI figures from 2022 to 2025 into quarterly values so that the average of all the quarters coincides with the annual forecast. I know how to do it the easy way using the td() function, but the problem is that if I put the 2 historical quarters of 2022 into the disaggregated values, the average of 2022 is no longer the same as the annual value.

Is there any way to incorporate the available historical figures when disaggregating?

I am adding example structures for reproducability:

```
# Generate fictional annual CPI data for the years 2000 to 2025
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
annual_cpi <- data.frame(Year = 2000:2025, CPI = runif(26, min = 100, max = 200))

# Generate fictional quarterly CPI data until 2022 Q2
quarterly_cpi <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2022-06-30"), by = "quarter"),
                            CPI = runif(90, min = 100, max = 200))


# Import annual CPI data and convert to time series
annual_cpi_ts <- ts(annual_cpi$CPI, start = c(2000, 1), frequency = 1)

# Import quarterly CPI data and convert to time series
quarterly_cpi_ts <- ts(quarterly_cpi$CPI, start = c(2000, 1), frequency = 4)
```